# Power builder Data window - Right to left

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a field in power builder in which `Right to left` is enabled in properties, I still need this to be RTL as I am using Arabic, but now I lost the option to `center` align it. Even if I change `alignment` property it is still right aligned.

[image]

Is there a way to center align the field even with `Right to left` is enabled?

Comment: Have you tried using a Modify statement in your code?  Did that make any difference?

Comment: @MattBalent, I think `modify` can only be used in user objects right, sorry newbie in power builder

Comment: Look up the datawindow modify method in the Help.  You would issue the command within the code of your application, maybe just after the data is retrieved into the datawindow.